# What replaces the functionality of WCF RIA Services?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

We've just entered the development phase of our project.  We're trying to define the best long-term supportable architecture that we can while providing a service layer that other LOB applications can be bolted onto later.  In the conceptual stage, an ESB seemed like the best bet, but there's no corporate standard ESB, and implementing one just for our project seems like taking a freight truck to the grocery store.

I did a little digging and found WCF RIA Services.  Hey, perfect, just what I wanted.  Sure, it's default state is for Silverlight, but it works with ASP.NET clients just as well.  But then it seems like [Microsoft is dumping RIA Services](http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/who-moved-my-cheese-ria-services/).  So, what should I use instead?  I don't want to implement a "new" technology here that is dead before our project gets started.  I looked at [Open RIA Services](http://www.openriaservices.net/), but that seems to be hospice care for the technology more than anything else.

My goal of separating the App Logic/Persistence layer from the Presentation and Business Rules layers holds.  We prefer to stay within the .NET ecosystem.  So, what is Microsoft issuing to replace WCF RIA, if anything?

Comment: The much more important choice will be the client technology, and the rest follows from that. Even if you decided on a web application already, the question is still whether it will be a classical one or a single-page dynamic one. Only in the latter case you need something like RIA Services, but getting this style of application right is still much more challenging.

Answer (score 2):

ServiceStack is one proprietary framework built on top of .Net that may fit to your needs, give it a look [Here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack).

Answer (score 2):

RIA is more about code generation...

[What is WCF RIA services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684421/what-is-wcf-ria-services)

I think Microsoft is steering towards REST based services with their ASP.NET Web API...

http://www.asp.net/web-api
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833994(v=vs.108).aspx

In terms of client proxies for ASP.NET Web API, the primary means of consuming such services is in HTML Javascript...

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-6

http://proudmonkey.azurewebsites.net/asp-net-5-jump-start-to-angularjs-with-mvc-6-web-api/

Maybe not the answer you wanted but anything else is probably not a path most will follow.

You could also look at SignalR...

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started